# Getting partial routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my config/routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :landings do
  collection do
    get 'about'
  end
end
```

Which give me the following routes:

```
about_landings  GET     /landings/about(.:format)       landings#about
landings        GET     /landings(.:format)             landings#index
                POST    /landings(.:format)             landings#create
new_landing     GET     /landings/new(.:format)         landings#new
edit_landing    GET     /landings/:id/edit(.:format)    landings#edit
landing         GET     /landings/:id(.:format)         landings#show
                PATCH   /landings/:id(.:format)         landings#update
                PUT     /landings/:id(.:format)         landings#update
                DELETE  /landings/:id(.:format)         landings#destroy
```

I only need the about route, and possibly a couple of other static pages routes. What is the routes.rb syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
resources :landings, only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'about'
  end
end
```

Which will give you:

```
about_landings GET    /landings/about(.:format)  landings#about
```

Personally, I don't like `about_landings` as a path name (aesthetically), so I think I would do:

```
scope module: :landings do
  get 'about'
end
```

Which will give you:

```
about GET    /about(.:format)  landings#about
```

And then you can just use `about_path` which IMO is nicer (and, you type fewer characters while building `routes.rb` thereby adding fractional seconds to your overall lifespan). Also, you get a cleaner (again, IMO) url in the browser address bar.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. I agree, the module route is "cleaner"

Comment: Great! Hope it works for you. Please feel free to upvote/accept as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  except / only

```
resources :landings, except: [:show, :new, :edit] do
  collection do
    get 'about'
  end
end
```

OR

```
resources :landings, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    get 'about'
  end
end
```

**NOTE: you can skip or allow only specific action.I just given example**

Comment: Yes, this works. I was wondering if there's a syntax, that will disable all the default routes, without having to list them individually